# calculate average in separate column over period and group by date Standard SQL BigQuery

Tags: sql, date, google-bigquery, average, group

I have a table in BQ that looks like this:

```
date          rate 
02/02/22       null
02/01/22       null
01/31/22        1
01/30/22        1.5
01/29/22        0.5
```

I want to create `avg_rate` column. I tried simple calculations for averages but because I have a group by statement - it assigns nulls to the avg_rate column. I need each date where the rate is null to grab all sums of rate that are not nulls and divide by rows count (for those that has not nulls for rate) and assign this number to each date.
Here is my query:

```
SELECT
  date,
  SUM(rate) / COUNT(*) AS avg_rate
FROM
  `my_table`
GROUP BY
  1
```

The output I a getting:

```
date          avg_rate 
02/02/22       null
02/01/22       null
01/31/22        1
01/30/22        1.5
01/29/22        0.5
```

Desired output is:

```
date          avg_rate 
02/02/22        1
02/01/22        1
01/31/22        1
01/30/22        1.5
01/29/22        0.5
```

Comment: Where does 2.66666 come from?

Comment: Well it's an average of those three values I have. The formula is in the query.

Comment: I added one more date in my calculations, fixed now in the question. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `coalesce` to return the `avg` grouped by date, and if it's `null` return the total average of the column instead using a subquery:

```
select date, coalesce(avg(rate), (select avg(rate) from my_table))
from my_table
group by date
```

Answer (score -1):

Suppose you have this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  select 1 as i union select 2 union select null
) x;
```

This will output:

| i |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| NULL |

With some aggregate functions added:

```
select avg(i), count(i), sum(i), count(*) 
from (
   select 1 as i union select 2 union select null
) x;
```

The output is:

| avg(i) | count(i) | sum(i) | count(*) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.5000 | 2 | 3 | 3 |

- As you can see `count(i)` counts the not null values
- and `count(*)` counts all the values

Comment: But how am I to apply this when there is a date column as well? The issue is that the query has to group it by day, or else I have an error that my data is neither grouped nor aggregated.

Comment: When no `GROUP BY` is supplied, all records are grouped into one, and it does not really matter what type the column, that is being `GROUP BY`-ed  has.  My answer is just showing the basics of `AVG()`, `COUNT()` and `SUM()`m because in your question you said: "I want to create avg_rate column"